# How to Isolate Device on a Router to Internet-Only

Tags: iptables

Similar to the way "Wireless Isolation" works as a feature on advanced routers, I want to ensure that wired clients cannot access any other members of the LAN/VLAN, (but they should be able to access the internet).

Each of the four physical ports for wired devices have been assigned a static ip (x.x.x.66 as below), and each is in their own VLAN.  I want to ensure that they can't hit any other devices in their VLAN.

Here's what I added to the router's firewall script:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.0.1.66 -d 10.0.1.0/24 -p all -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.0.2.66 -d 10.0.2.0/24 -p all -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.0.3.66 -d 10.0.3.0/24 -p all -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.0.4.66 -d 10.0.4.0/24 -p all -j DROP
```

Unfortunately it does not prevent me from being able to ping from e.g. 10.0.1.66 to 10.0.1.116.  Everything else about my iptables setup works as expected.

Here's the complete Iptables output (note that br0-br3 are the VLANs):

```
iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 21 packets, 2322 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  br3    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br3    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  br3    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:67 
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  br3    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  br3    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with tcp-reset 
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  br3    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:67 
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with tcp-reset 
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  br1    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br1    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53 
    2  1152 ACCEPT     udp  --  br1    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:67 
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  br1    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  br1    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with tcp-reset 
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  br1    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
   34  2951 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
  369 49487 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    2   180 shlimit    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 state NEW 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  102  8187 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br1    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br3    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     2    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4         udp dpt:!1900 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       10.0.4.66            10.0.4.0/24         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       10.0.3.66            10.0.3.0/24         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       10.0.2.66            10.0.2.0/24         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       10.0.1.66            10.0.1.0/24         
 1456  377K            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           account: network/netmask: 10.0.1.0/255.255.255.0 name: lan 
    6   328            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           account: network/netmask: 10.0.2.0/255.255.255.0 name: lan1 
    4   160            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           account: network/netmask: 10.0.3.0/255.255.255.0 name: lan2 
   18  1136            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           account: network/netmask: 10.0.4.0/255.255.255.0 name: lan3 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br1    br1     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br2    br2     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br3    br3     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5   200 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
 1367  363K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br0    br1     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br0    br2     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br0    br3     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br1    br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br1    br2     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br1    br3     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br2    br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br2    br1     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br2    br3     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br3    br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br3    br1     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br3    br2     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3   147 wanin      all  --  vlan2  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  109 15477 wanout     all  --  *      vlan2   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  107 15377 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1    60 ACCEPT     all  --  br1    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1    40 ACCEPT     all  --  br3    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3   147 upnp       all  --  vlan2  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 326 packets, 202K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a misunderstanding of the network layers and how traffic is delivered.

What you seem to be missing is that devices on the same LAN communicate at layer-2. The traffic will not go through the layer-3 router, except when traveling from one network (LAN) to another, it goes directly from one device to the other on the same LAN, using the layer-2 (e.g. MAC) LAN address.

Some switches provide the type of isolation you want. Search for Private VLANs. You could also create separate VLANs and addressing for each, and connect the devices to separate VLANs. You could then prevent traffic at layer-3 (e.g. IPv4 and/or IPv6) from crossing VLANs.

Comment: Understood, in fact the network is already VLANed; the problem arises because the operating software (Tomato) can't support enough VLANs to keep all my devices isolated - I'd need 8, and Tomato only supports 4, so what I'm trying to do is a bit clunky (isolate inside a VLAN).  Tomato does not support private VLANS, either.  Would a MAC-based iptables policy work, or would it not be triggered for intra-VLAN packets?  Is there an alternative option?

Comment: The traffic within a VLAN does not traverse your router. All the devices use the same layer-3 network. Routers route between networks. You cannot apply a layer-3 filer like iptables withing a layer-2 network.